# issue with using await/async for my function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm trying to have 3 fetch calls in my function.

First one:

This one gets me a random joke

```
fetch('https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Programming')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((actualResponse) => (joke = actualResponse.joke));
```

Second one:

I have to request a joke from a bot, think of it as a chatbot type of design. I ask for "hey, give me a joke" and then it gives me one. This one will get the "hey, give me a joke" send it to the back end and react will render it later on.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3002/jarvis/add', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        text: messageInput.current.value,
        author: 1,
      }),
    }).then((res) => res.json());
```

Third one:

This one is similar to the second one, its supposed to give the joke key the value of the joke variable, send it to the back end, and then react renders it later on.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3002/jarvis/add', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        joke: joke,
      }),
    }).then((res) => res.json());
```

My react can render things like this, so sending it to the backend and rendering works. I got a weather API working like this for example. I don't understand why this one isn't working out though, it feels like maybe its because it runs other functions before finishing? I don't know honestly and would appreciate someone more experienced feedback

I have realized I might need to use async/await, can someone point out why the following is not working? In my mind it does the first function, then the second one, then lastly the third one. It makes sense to me, clearly it's still not right though. This is the full code now:

```
async function getJoke() {
    let joke = 'Im a robot';

    await fetch('https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Programming')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((actualResponse) => (joke = actualResponse.joke));

    await fetch('http://localhost:3002/jarvis/add', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        text: messageInput.current.value,
        author: 1,
      }),
    }).then((res) => res.json());

    await fetch('http://localhost:3002/jarvis/add', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        joke: joke,
      }),
    }).then((res) => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: Your calls are running in the right order, but you're not returning any of the calls - the results of both `/all` fetches go unused. Did you mean to return them or assign them to a variable and use the variable, or something?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, it's just supposed to post it to the db and react renders it later on

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "isn't working", can you be a bit more specific? Other than not using the results of any of the calls, there doesn't look to be anything obviously wrong with the code you have

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, sorry. So my code in the second fetch is sending an empty string for messageInput.current.value. When console logging it right below the joke variable, it gives me "jarvis joke".

At first it didn't even send the joke, from the joke api. now with the awaits that is working.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with the `messageInput` identifier and how this whole function is being called, not with the code inside this function

Comment: @CertainPerformance but the identifier works with my weather api part of the app, and within this function itself the console log for the messageInput identifier works too, just for some reason it sends an empty string

Comment: Don't do `….then((actualResponse) => (joke = actualResponse.joke))`. Just `const {joke} = await …;`!